# Always show plan options view in stripe

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

When a user has had two plans in the past they have the option to toggle which plan like this:
[image: stripe dashboard with 2 product options]

But if they are on the lower plan then they can only see their current product option like so:
[image: stripe dashboard with 1 product option]

How can I always show the first version even if they have only one option? Thanks!

I am using laravel cashier to interface with stripe.

There is also always a way to update quantity for the basic plan but never for the premium plan even though both are set up the same.

Comment: Did you have any custom [Customer Portal Configurations](https://docs.stripe.com/api/customer_portal/configurations) for this customer portal? It's likely that some configurations of the customer portal causes the one plan being shown. I'd recommend writing into Stripe [Support](https://docs.stripe.com/api/customer_portal/configurations) to have a check what might have misconfigured.